# Cannot read property of undefined in templates

Tags: javascript, json, object, angular

In my component template, I'm getting output as [output:Output] but not what I wanted. I'm sending an object from a parent container using @Output

In my template when I try to bind `{{selectedMovDetail|json}}` the output is `{ "name": "The Walking Dead","rating":"8.6"}`

But when I try to extract data using `{{selectedMovDetail['name']}}` I get the following error

[image]

When I tried to debug with Augury (chrome debug tool) I get

[image]

Now I'm confused how to extract the object values.
Any help regarding this is much appreciated

Comment: Can you try `selectedMovDetail?.name` istead of `selectedMovDetail['name']` please?

Comment: Oh..it worked thx.. what and why should we use '?'

Comment: The JsonPipe can handle the initial case, where that data *simply hasn't loaded yet*. You can also solve this with an `ngIf` or resolving the observable that provides the data using the `AsyncPipe`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: `selectedMovDetail?.name` instead of `selectedMovDetail['name']`.

When you use the "elvis" operator, `?`, in selecting your json keys, it will not throw an error if it can't find a specific key or the value has not been loaded yet (only in html).

For example in your case: `selectedMovDetail.name` exists after the template has been viewed so using `?` before the `.` makes sure that name will be printed when it's loaded.